# Merge two or more cells into one in ALASQL

Tags: jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, alasql

I'm trying to export excel using alasql in angularJS. Here I need to merge two or more cells into one what we do using colspan in HTML. Would be great if someone can help me with that. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After searching for a while I found that currently, ALASQL doesn't support this functionality. Following is the link to GITHUB where the issue has been listed and answered:
[GITHUB](https://github.com/agershun/alasql/issues/981)